# Android Studio disable lightbulb

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I want to disable the light bulb (lint checking / intentions) in Android Studio:

[image]

Some clarifications:

1. The main reason I want to disable this light bulb, is because I find myself several times copying and pasting strings, however the light bulb gets in the way and gets accidentally clicked.
2. If I press Alt+Enter, I can see the same suggestions that the light bulb is showing. Therefore, why would I need the light bulb to appear all the time since I can manually enable it by pressing Alt+Enter?
3. I have already disabled all intentions in Android Studio: File > Settings > Editor > Intentions
4. I have already added the following line: < option name="SHOW_INTENTION_BULB" value="false" /> in %HOMEPATH%.\config\options\editor.xml as suggested by other users. This indeed reduces the time that the light bulb is appearing, however it stills appears when there's a warning in my code. I don't want to disable the warnings, I just want to make the light bulb disappear since I can always press Alt+Enter to see the available suggestions in a warning.

Thanks!

Comment: UX Team: Popups are great, put them everywhere!

Comment: @straya haha! You get a popup, and you get a popup, and you get a popup! ... Everybody gets a popup!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Uncheck `Show  intention bulb` under `Settings > Editor > General > Appearance`

Comment: Seems to work. Was this added in a recent Android Studio version?

Comment: Yes, it's a recent addition. Don't know which version exactly.

Comment: Finally!  I don't know how many hours I've wasted by this distracting "helper!"

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible. However when it is visible, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will make the light bulb disappear. See also [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94381).

Answer (score 0):

(Workaround) If you disable the entries that appear as suggestions on the light bulb, it will disappear. (Direct disabling is not possible)

```
1. Settings > Editor > Inspections > Language Injection
2. Settings > Editor > Intentions > Android > Override Resource in Other Configuration ...
```

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score -3):

I find it sometimes annoying, but its very good handy & i'm sure you don't want it to be disabled forever. however what you can do is, you could click **right-arrow** on `Typo:Change to..` & click on **disable inspection**  as a fast way to do it only for the meantime & not forever.

Comment: The question was how to disable the lightbulb, not disable one instance of the lightbulb. It is clear from the question that the OP wants them ALL to stop appearing. A comment is a better place to make a bad assumption than in an answer.